# iPhone and Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, object

I need some understanding about using Core Data.

Can it be used to save and retrieve all of my objects used in my program?

Is there any simple example demonstrating this ?

I am having hard time finding one online.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have to be managed objects, but you can convert them all to be - it's just that you still have to define the data model for them.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you ultimately vote up or mark as accepted, but it may prove useful if you haven't seen it already:

[Apple: Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html)

I found it endlessly useful personally.